# API reference for cocos2d-iphone js bindings

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is there any API reference for cocos2d-iphone javascript bindings ?

I found the [API reference for cocos2d-html5](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/index.html) but there are obviously some differences... For instance I'm trying to extend cc.Sprite class and the initWithFile method cannnot be found (whereas it exists in cocos2d-html5).

Does such a documentation exist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for the moment the best "documentation" is the cocos2d-js-tests:
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-js-tests